# keep keyboard from hiding UITextField at bottom of UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, keyboard, uitextfield

According to the answer at [UITableView, make footer stay at bottom of screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18047720/uitableview-make-footer-stay-at-bottom-of-screen), which I verify:

> In order to have a footer that stays put at the bottom of the screen,
>   and doesn't scroll with the table, then you can't use a table view
>   footer. You can't even use a UITableViewController, you'll need to
>   implement your view controller as a UIViewController. Then you add
>   your own table view as a subview. You'll also need to add your footer
>   as a subview of the view controller's view, not the table view. Make
>   sure you size the table view so its bottom is at the top of the footer
>   view.

but the problem is that my UITextField, inside my footer, is being hidden by the keyboard when user tries to type. So how do I keep the keyboard from hiding the UITextField? Throughout the app, I have been using TPKeyboardAvoiding. But in this case, where a UIScrollView/TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView contains a UITableView and a UIView in vertical order, it does not work. I generally like TPKeyboardAvoiding because it’s so quick and easy. Any ideas how I might fix this issue?

Comment: Can't you do it the old-fashioned way but sliding up self.view of the UIViewController and then sliding it down again?

Comment: @Darren, I am looking at that. But the best code I find so far has the keyboard data hard-coded as magic numbers. So I am looking for ways to combine that code with keyboard notification somehow. The code is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247113/iphone-keyboard-covers-uitextfield?rq=1

Comment: Don't add the UITextField into your UITableView's footer. Add it as a subview of the UIViewController as stated in the quoted text.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. But unfortunately, not one of them is of much help :) You guys are just repeating exactly what I said I already did. I **am** using a UIViewController and a UITableView and a UIView below the UITableView. The UIView that I am using as "footer" contains a UITextField and a Button. I am the one who provided the quote. So No. I am not using a UITableView footer. Anyway. I new code I find has some issues in that it shows a black screen for a moment after the keyboard is gone. Plus the numbers are hardcoded magic numbers. Any ideas how to fix those issues?

Answer (score 1):

The instruction that you quote is telling you to use a UIViewController, add a UITableView as a subview, then add a UITextField as a subview of the UIViewController NOT as a subview of the UITableView.

Let me draw it out for you:

### Step 1:

Add a UITableView to your view controller

[image]

### Step 2:

Add your UITextField subview (you can embed the UITextField in a UIView container if you like) as a subview of your UIViewController's view NOT your UITableView footer.

[image]

### Step 3:

If depending on if your using frames or autolayout, you adjust the frame or autolayout constraint constant values for your UITextField subview when user tap on the text field.

[image]

### Step 4:

Finally, the keyboard appears and the UITextField doesn't get obscured by the keyboard.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure your UITableView doesn't initialize it's own automatic scrolling for keyboard appearing. If you use UITableViewController then just subclass it and make sure you don't call it's viewWillAppear:. I didn't investigate which exactly method you should block without using UITableViewController, so, you should find out this yourself or somebody else would help.

I did similar in my own project where I wanted to have own scrolling of table view for keyboard appearing.