# IOS Swift, show textfield at the bottom of table

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am doing chat screen, in that i want to add my text field at bottom of the table.
I have used footer of the table but problem is that if table height is less then footer will not appear on the bottom of screen. like given below.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you want to use footer of the table view? Any specific reason for that?

One best way to handle this is to Use UITableViewController in a storyboard, and embed it within a UIViewController as a container view. Then you can use auto layout to set the relationship between the footer and the container view which contains the UITableView.

Original answer :

[tableFooterView property doesn't fix the footer at the bottom of the table view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15687370/tablefooterview-property-doesnt-fix-the-footer-at-the-bottom-of-the-table-view)

[UITableView, make footer stay at bottom of screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18047720/uitableview-make-footer-stay-at-bottom-of-screen)