# Toolbar in a TableView (Swift)

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitoolbar

I have a Toolbar at the bottom of my TableView in Storyboard within a ViewController. When I run the app, the toolbar only shows at the bottom of the table view. How can I make the toolbar fixed like the navigation bar? Do I need to have a tab bar controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: true)
```

and use storyboard to customise the ToolBar

Comment: My app is now showing two toolbars...the one I have in Storyboard and the one from setToolBarHidden. I deleted the storyboard one I had. How do I customize the one from your code using storyboard?

Comment: im not sure how you could have two toolbars,how did you make your first toolbar?did you just make a footer and are calling it a toolbar?

Comment: to customise the tool bar in storyboard select the viewController then in the attributes inspector -> simulated metrics -> set the bottom bar to translucent toolbar,then you can drag bar button items to that bar and hook them up to IBActions

Answer (score 0):

..this question may be a duplicate of [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18047720/2683201) 
and [thisone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19625416/2683201). There you will find some insight.
Nevertheless, if what you are trying to do is to keep that view on top of all the others, then you should go ahead and try solutions depicted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6622913/2683201)