# Subview on top of window view in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I want to place a UIView over the entire screen (including the navigation bar). This view will be black with 0.3 opacity. I want to do this to darken out the screen content and push a view on top of this. I am using this code:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.addSubview(darkView)
```

This covers the whole screen as expected. However I now want to place another view on top of this dark view. Is there a way to do this? Everything I try just results in the view being under the dark view. Any pointers would be really appreciated! thanks

Comment: You will need to show the code for what you have tried

Comment: Why don't you just present a semi-transparent full screen controller from your current controller? If you think you need to add a view to the window, you are probably doing it wrong.

Comment: You should implement this with custom transition, not this way.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

It's *really* simple.

You just add another view to `window`! And it will be there, on top of the first view you added. For example, this code adds a black view and a white view:

```
let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!
let v = UIView(frame: window.bounds)
window.addSubview(v)
v.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
let v2 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 50))
v2.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
window.addSubview(v2)
```

You can also add the new view as a sub view of the first view you added:

```
let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!
let v = UIView(frame: window.bounds)
window.addSubview(v)
v.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
let v2 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 50))
v2.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
v.addSubview(v2)
```

**Swift 4**

```
let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!
let v = UIView(frame: window.bounds)
window.addSubview(v)
v.backgroundColor = .black
let v2 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 50))
v2.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
v.addSubview(v2)
```

Simple!

Comment: Thanks for this, however is there a way of bringing a view from an existing view controller to the front of views in the window without directly adding it in though?

Comment: @Kex No, as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: In my case UIView is not covering entire screen.

Comment: After showing the alert view, when we want to show the popupwindowView, that is misplacing.

Comment: Need to change window variable as -----
let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.last!

Answer (score 24):

For SWIFT 3 use this:

```
let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!
window.addSubview(someView)
```

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 5:**

```
let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.last!

let viewToShow = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: window.frame.size.width, height: 40.0))

viewToShow.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

window.addSubview(viewToShow)
```

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 4**,
Adding a **UIViewController** as a subview to **UIWindow**

This code is for adding view controller as a subview, covering the whole window with simple animation.

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
var customReviewPopup = ReviewPopupViewController.init(nibName: "ReviewPopupViewController", bundle: Bundle.main)

self.appDelegate.window?.addSubview((customReviewPopup.view)!)
self.customReviewPopup.view.frame = (self.appDelegate.window?.bounds)!
self.customReviewPopup.view.alpha = 0
self.customReviewPopup.view.isHidden = true

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
    self.customReviewPopup.view.isHidden = false
    self.customReviewPopup.view.alpha = 1
}, completion: nil)
```

Comment: After showing the alert view, when we want to show the popupwindowView, that is misplacing.

Answer (score 1):

```
UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first?.windowScene?.windows.last  //This is better

UIApplication.shared.windows.last! //This will some times has bug, because system will add other scene into Application in runtime, for example add subview in UIImagePickerController`
```