# In iOS using swift, how do I create a draggable and floating UIView that is always on the top of throughout the entire app

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

- I want to keep the UIView always on top (not the top of the
  ViewController) throughout the entire app like youtube player???
- I want to make this UIView draggable to the screen?
  [image]

Comment: you can keep in your navigation controller... or design your application in such a way whenever viewcontroller open it must have top view

Comment: elaborate your answer a little more. @ShauketSheikh

Comment: Refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38540091/subview-on-top-of-window-view-in-swift

Comment: create a base controller and inherit that controller with each controller, in base controller add a view like header at top

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code to add a view to your application window

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let newView = UIView()
    newView.frame = CGRect(x:0,y:UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 30)
    newView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    let label = UILabel()
    label.frame = newView.bounds
    label.text = "header"
    newView.addSubview(label)
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(newView)

    let bounds = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: newView.frame.size.height + newView.frame.origin.y, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height  )
}
```

Please check and let me know if this works

Comment: this worked but there is a problem, when i dismiss the view controller and navigation controller then everything get stopped. This means i lost all the references of view controller.

Comment: Try to use single navigation controller from the AppDelegate

Answer (score 0):

UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(UIView)