# In swift， How to keep a UIViewController().view at the top？like UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I'm using `CustomAlertViewController` as an Alert on `UIViewController`. Current code snippet to present `CustomAlertViewController` -

```
CustomAlertViewController: UIViewController {}
self.present(CustomAlertViewController(), animated: true, completion: {})
```

But I want to add`CustomAlertViewController`on top of the view hierarchy.

Any suggestion how to achieve this?

Comment: What? Explain why you need to do that

Comment: add in `Window` rather than present it on `viewController`.

Comment: like UIAlertController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
extension UIViewController {
  func showAlertConfirm(errorMessage: String, operation: @escaping ()->()) {
  let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Confirmation", message: errorMessage, 
  preferredStyle: .alert)

  let confirmationAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action) 
         in
           operation()
   }
 let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler:nil)
    alert.addAction(confirmationAction)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } 
 }
```

if you call this function

```
 showAlertConfirm(errorMessage: "Test", operation:
    requestData()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want to add your UIViewCotroller’s view as a subview of key window. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38540271/5779168

Comment: but this view cant controller