# How to add a button at bottom of every page with UIPageViewController?

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I used a `UIPageViewController` to present some pages. On every swipe, I feed a `UITableviewController` to `UIPageViewController`, using `tableview` to present a page. Now I want to add a button at bottom of every page. I have tried in two ways: first: adding button to tableview's superview and bring it to front

```
 [self.tableView.superview addSubview:submitButton];
//[self.tableView.superview bringSubviewToFront:submitButton];
```

second: adding button to pageviewcontroller's view and bring it to front

```
[strongSelf.pageViewController.view addSubview:submitButton];
[strongSelf.pageViewController.view bringSubviewToFront:submitButton];
```

But neither is OK, nothing appeared! Thanks in advance!

Comment: the button stay there unscrollable

Comment: add it into keywindow

Comment: would you please elaborate on this?

Comment: Read it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622913/how-to-add-uiview-on-the-top-of-all-views

Comment: It works. It's a great help. Thank you very much!!

Comment: which one works?

Comment: The third solution, add subview to the first subview of key window. One more thing, could you please tell me why the two method I've tried don't work?

Comment: And in my case, the first subview of window is a tableview. Why the button scroll as the tableview scroll. I want to know the reason, problem solved though.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the button to Table view -> Footer view.

Comment: adding a footer view maybe a little bit troublesome, is there any way more simple and clean? ps: what is wrong with addsubview to superview?